# TypeORM: can I get the ids of deleted relations to clean up s3 objects?

Tags: typescript, amazon-s3, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following property on a `Onboarding` entity:

```
@OneToMany(() => Tool, (tool) => tool.onboarding, {
    cascade: true,
    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
})
tools: Tool[];
```

A `Tool` has a relation to a `File` (representation for an S3 object):

```
@ApiProperty()
@OneToOne(() => File)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'file_id' })
public image: File;
```

Now to my question:
How can I find the file ids that are being deleted when one or more tools are deleted? I want to clean up the according S3 objects so we don't have clutter in our bucket.

At the moment the tools are deleted "implicitely" like this:

```
await this.onboardingRepository.save({
    ...existingOnboarding,
    tools: updatedTools // this is an array of tools from a request
});
```

I'd like to get an array of ids of the deleted `File` entities to then proceed to delete them.

Edit: I tried to use typeORM's subscribers, but it's not possible to inject nestjs services into these which is a problem.

Comment: Which problem do you encounter when injecting services into your subscribers?

Comment: @W.S. nestjs dependency injection doesn't work in TypeORM subscribers. This even is documented in multiple TypeORM issues.

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/pull/27#issuecomment-431296683 ?

Comment: @W.S. Yes, this only gives me a connection though. I need a service --> this is why I abandoned the Subscriber approach.

Comment: According to this stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918644/nestjs-cannot-inject-a-service-into-a-subscriber, you should be able to inject services after you injected the connection first and push it to the subscribers.