# Manually register a typeorm EventSubscriber in NestJS without specifying it in the configuration file

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm, typescript-decorator, nestjs-config

In NestJS I extended the class EntitySubscriberInterface to create a generic EventSubscriber.

My goal is to catch all the typeorm repository events 'beforeInsert' every time that I insert something in the DB (it should be triggered for all the entities).


This code is working because the file is saved in one of the folder inside the src folder in NestJS and the path to it is specified in the NestJS configuaration file; in doing so the subscriber file is automatically loaded.


My goal would be to move this file inside a npm package so that I could extract it from the main logic of the NestJS app and then initialize it when needed doing something like 'new ValidatorSubscriber()';

Is it possible? Because all my attempts so far have failed.

I tried in the app.module.ts to initialize my ValidatorSubscriber class and the constructor is correctly called but then the subscribers are not working.

Any idea?

```
import { EntitySubscriberInterface, EventSubscriber, InsertEvent } from 'typeorm';

@EventSubscriber()
export class ValidatorSubscriber<T> implements EntitySubscriberInterface<T> {

    private entitiesMap = new Map();

    constructor() {
        console.log('EventSubscriber constructor')
        import('../db/entities') // get all entities
            .then((allEntities: any) => {
                for (const prop in allEntities) {
                    this.entitiesMap.set(prop, allEntities[prop])
                }

                console.log(allEntities)
            });
    }
    /**
     * Called before post insertion.
     */
    async beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>): Promise<void> {
        console.log(`BEFORE INSERTION, ${JSON.stringify(event.entity)}`)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case someone needs it, I managed to find a solution.

I combined the answer from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918644/nestjs-cannot-inject-a-service-into-a-subscriber) with the answer [provided here](https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/pull/27) by fwoelffel (see screenshot of the answer).

Keep in mind that InjectConnection is deprecated, I used this instead:

```
constructor(
    @Inject(Connection) readonly connection: Connection,
) {
```

[image]