# Nest JS TypeORM inject service

Tags: mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using nestjs with typeorm. For my audit log I have created typeorm subscriber but I cant able to inject my service in to it.

When I call the function from the service im getting error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined` also when I do console `console.log(this.activityLogService);` in subscriber hook it shows undefined.

FYI: I have tried by adding `@Injectable()` aswell

```
@EventSubscriber()
export class GlobalSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {

  constructor(private activityLogService: ActivityLogService) {}

  afterUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>) {
    console.log(this.activityLogService); // This is undefined
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NestJS - Cannot inject a service into a subscriber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58918644/nestjs-cannot-inject-a-service-into-a-subscriber)